# easily add hover animation to SVG from SVG sprite

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I'm buliding an SVG sprite as follows:

```
<body>
    <svg display="none" width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
    <symbol id="icon-arrow-down" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
      <title>arrow-down</title>
      <path class="path1" d="M715.215 393.582l-204.117 204.166-206.141-206.092c-9.533-9.533-24.942-9.533-34.475 0s-9.533 24.966 0 34.475l223.378 223.33c4.584 4.584 10.776 7.144 17.237 7.144s12.678-2.56 17.237-7.144l221.355-221.403c9.533-9.533 9.533-24.966 0-34.475-9.533-9.533-24.942-9.533-34.475 0z"></path>
      <path class="path2" d="M512 0c-282.331 0-512 229.669-512 512s229.669 512 512 512c282.307 0 512-229.693 512-512s-229.693-512-512-512zM512 975.238c-255.439 0-463.238-207.799-463.238-463.238s207.799-463.238 463.238-463.238 463.238 207.799 463.238 463.238c0 255.439-207.799 463.238-463.238 463.238z"></path>
    </symbol>
    </defs>
    </svg>



      <div class="arrow-down arrow-wrap">
                     <svg class="icon icon-arrow-down"><use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-down"></use></svg>
                </div>
```

What I would like to do is animate the paths for example turn a triangle into a square. I guess it has to be done with Snap.svg, but how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `<animate>` to animate the `d` attribute with the one restriction that the paths have to match as far as the curves and lines go.  So for instance, if you original path is one line followed by a curve and 2 lines, your animation must animate to the same, though you can change the coordinates for each.  This can be a bit tricky depending on the shapes you are trying to morph and may require things like using a curve but providing values that actually makes it a straight line, etc.

For example, by changing just the first `M` and the first two lines in your animation, you can get this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hp7ncyy2/1/

```html
<svg display="none" width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="icon-arrow-down" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
            <title>arrow-down</title>
            <path class="path1">
                <animate attributeName="d" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="
                        M715.215 393.582l-204.117 204.166-206.141-206.092c-9.533-9.533-24.942-9.533-34.475 0s-9.533 24.966 0 34.475l223.378 223.33c4.584 4.584 10.776 7.144 17.237 7.144s12.678-2.56 17.237-7.144l221.355-221.403c9.533-9.533 9.533-24.966 0-34.475-9.533-9.533-24.942-9.533-34.475 0z;
                        M715.215 493.582l-204.117 -204.166-206.141 206.092c-9.533-9.533-24.942-9.533-34.475 0s-9.533 24.966 0 34.475l223.378 223.33c4.584 4.584 10.776 7.144 17.237 7.144s12.678-2.56 17.237-7.144l221.355-221.403c9.533-9.533 9.533-24.966 0-34.475-9.533-9.533-24.942-9.533-34.475 0z;
                        M715.215 393.582l-204.117 204.166-206.141-206.092c-9.533-9.533-24.942-9.533-34.475 0s-9.533 24.966 0 34.475l223.378 223.33c4.584 4.584 10.776 7.144 17.237 7.144s12.678-2.56 17.237-7.144l221.355-221.403c9.533-9.533 9.533-24.966 0-34.475-9.533-9.533-24.942-9.533-34.475 0z" />
            </path>
            <path class="path2" d="M512 0c-282.331 0-512 229.669-512 512s229.669 512 512 512c282.307 0 512-229.693 512-512s-229.693-512-512-512zM512 975.238c-255.439 0-463.238-207.799-463.238-463.238s207.799-463.238 463.238-463.238 463.238 207.799 463.238 463.238c0 255.439-207.799 463.238-463.238 463.238z"></path>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
<div class="arrow-down arrow-wrap">
    <svg class="icon icon-arrow-down">
        <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-down"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

This is obviously not a perfect square, but you get the basic idea.  You would need to manipulate the path to get the exact shape you want.

If you change the number or type of commands in the path, the animate will just jump back and forth with no animation.